# ServerSocket.accept() is a blocking method -- multiple listeners to speed up?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

In the application, 
the `ServerSocket` instance is accepting a connection 
and passing it to a thread right on. The connections at that port 
are all threaded-- one thread for one connection. The socket listener looks something like this:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
for (;;) {  // keep listening
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  
   Thread t = new LRcvr(socket);  
   t.start();
}
```

What i'm wondering is, is there more to do to 
speed this up in high-traffic conditions on that socket.

I am specifically concerned about [`ServerSocket.accept()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29). 
In multiple connection requests, say `req-1` & `req-2`, 
`req-1` arrives at the port before `req-2`. However, the connection between the socket & `req-1` 
isn't established timely for some reason of its own, and this blocks 
`req-2` being "heard" its request and thus get connected at the port.
This whole thing is because the method `ServerSocket.accept()` is a blocking one.

There must be a smart way to get around this. What is it?

Creating multiple socket listeners to hear&accept the connection requests 
comes to mind, but would that work - how? Should i multi-thread the socket listeners? 
What should be my concerns then?

Note: we can operate only one port-- multiple sockets is not an option here.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, req-1 will not block req-2 from being heard.

`ServerSocket.accept()` only blocks application-level handling of new connections, and it is triggered when a connection is established.

If a connection with req-1 hasn't been established, it's not exposed to the application level yet. `accept()` will happily unblock as req-2 is connected.

(Spawning a new thread for every single connection may be a problem though. What if you accept 10 000 connections? I'm not sure modern JVMs and/or kernels can efficiently handle this amount of threads.)

Comment: what do you mean "application-level handling of new connections" - can you be more specific

Comment: All low-level stuff for a TCP connection is normally handled by OS (kernel). OS listens to network, recognizes requests to establish a TCP connection, performs all this three-way-handshake-stuff etc. What you described in your example could happen at OS level, but the OS processes connections in a non-blocking way, no problem there. When you call `accept()`, you're basically asking OS to give you a first ready-to-use connection, and if there is no ready connection, the call will block your application. The OS is not blocked by the call. That's what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

> In multiple connection requests, say req-1 & req-2,  req-1 arrives at the port before req-2. However, the connection between the socket & req-1 isn't established timely for some reason of its own

Some reason such as? Define. In any case, if the connection isn't established, it never gets to the TCP backlog queue, let alone to the accept() method.

> and this blocks  req-2 being "heard" its request

No it doesn't.

> and thus get connected at the port.

No it doesn't. Connection requests are processed completely by TCP and placed in the backlog queue regardless of what accept() is or isn't doing.

> This whole thing is because the method ServerSocket.accept() is a blocking one.

No it isn't. First of all 'this whole thing' doesn't even exist, and secondly the fact that accept() is blocking had zero bearing on it.

> There must be a smart way to get around this.

There is nothing here to 'get around'. Your problem is imaginary.